# Reversing a directed graph preserves acyclicness?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Suppose we have an arbitrary directed graph $G$.

We create a related new graph $G'$ by reversing every edge in $G$.

Is this statement true or false?: *$G$ is acyclic if and only if $G'$ is acyclic.*

Comment: That's trivial.

Comment: If $G$ has a directed circuit, $G'$ has the same circuit, just the direction of its edges get reversed.

Comment: Considering the contrapositive, isn't the reverse of a cycle a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ has a cycle; call this path $C$. Reversing every edge in $C$ to produce $C'$, this reverse cycle exists in $G'$. Thus, $G$ having a cycle implies $G'$ having a cycle.

By the same reasoning, if $G'$ has a cycle, then it can be reversed to find a cycle in $G$. Thus, $G'$ having a cycle implies $G$ having a cycle.

Putting these two facts together, $G$ has a cycle if and only if $G'$ has a cycle.

And we can take the negation of both sides to say the same thing about acyclicness.